# Simple proof for complete, metric vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, smooth-functions

I have the vector space $C_c^\infty([a, b])=\{f \in C_c^\infty : supp(f) \subset [a, b] \}$ and a metric on this space with
$d(\varphi, \psi)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \frac{\lVert \varphi-\psi \rVert_n}{1 + \lVert \varphi-\psi \rVert_n} \text{, with } \lVert \varphi \rVert_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sup_{x \in [a, b]} \lvert \varphi^{(j)}(x) \rvert$
I already showed that it's a metric, but I have some trouble with completness.
Is there a simple proof or consideration that helps? Or even some literature with the proof?
I already found something on here with "$f_n \to f$  uniformly and $f_n' \to g$ uniformly then f is differentiable and g=f′ is repeateatly replied for the proof', but I don't know how this helps me.

Comment: Okay so for fixed $n$ and a Cauchy sequence $\{f_k\}$ in $C^n_c$, I know that the pointwise limits (g) exist, because $\{f_k(x)\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. The same is true for the derivatives (limits $g_j$). If I show now the uniform convergence of those limits, I could use the lemma and the uniform limit theorem to show the existence of the limit of the Cauchy sequence and that it belongs to $C_c^n$.
Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @AnneBauval What do I exactly need to show for uniform convergence in this case?
Or is it due to the nature of the norm $\lVert \dot \rVert $, that I don't even need to show uniform convergence, because it's already implied?

Comment: @AnneBauval what do I need to do now for the completness of $C_c^\infty$? I understand that I somehow have to show $d(f_n, f) < \epsilon$ and I will use what I just showed.  My idea now is: I know from before $C^n_c$ is complete and I can say that for arbitrary $\epsilon$ and each $n$ I have $N_n$ such that $\forall k \geq N_n$ $\lVert f_k - f \rVert_n < \frac{2 \epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$.
Then i get $d(f_k, f) \epsilon$ $\forall k \geq N=\min{N_n}$?

Comment: If you have a certain property $P_{k,n}$ for every $k\ge N_n$, what you get is only $\bigwedge_{k\ge M}P_{k,n}$ for every $k\ge M:=\color{red}{\max}N_n$, provided this max exists.

Comment: I think we can delete at least the (including this one of mine) 5 last comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(f_k)$ be a Cauchy sequence for $d$. Then, for every $n\in\Bbb N$, it is also Cauchy for the distance $(\varphi,\psi)\mapsto\frac{\lVert \varphi-\psi \rVert_n}{1 + \lVert \varphi-\psi \rVert_n}$, hence also for the norm $\|~\|_n$.

You "know that the pointwise limit $g$ exists, because $\{f_k(x)\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\Bbb R$ is complete. The same is true for the derivatives (limits $g_n
$)."

Now, these limits are actually not only pointwise, but even uniform. Let us prove it for instance for the first one, $f_k\to g$. Since $(f_k)$
is Cauchy for the uniform norm $\|~\|$ on $[a,b]$:
$$∀ϵ>0,∃N,∀j,k≥N,\|f_k−f_j\|≤ϵ$$
i.e.
$$ ∀x∈[a,b],\|f_k(x)−f_j(x)\|≤ϵ.$$
Therefore, since $(f_k)$ converges poinwise to $g$:
$$∀x∈[a,b],\|g(x)−f_j(x)\|≤ϵ$$
i.e. $\|g−f_j\|≤ϵ$, which ends the proof that $∀ϵ>0,∃N,∀j≥N,\|g−f_j\|≤ϵ$.

Using repeatedly the lemma you found, we are now sure that $(f_k)$ converges uniformly to some smooth function $g$ (whose support is then necessarily a subset of $[a,b]$) such that also $f_k^{(n)}\to g^{(n)}$ uniformly, for every $n\in\Bbb N$. There remains to derive that $d(f_k,g)\to0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. First choose some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{j>n}2^{-j}<\epsilon/2$. Now, since $d_j(f_k,g)$ tends to $0$ for every $j\in\{0,\dots,n\}$, so does $\sum_{j=0}^n2^{-j}d_j(f_k,g)$, which is therefore $<\epsilon/2$ for every large enough $k$. For such $k$s, $d(f_k,g)<\epsilon$, q.e.d.

Comment: Thanks for your help!